# Most secure way to communicate with my database?

Tags: php, mysql, http, security, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game in Unity which makes use of a remote MySQL database, hosted on a web server. Although it's entirely possible to communicate with a database directly from Unity/C#, I'm also aware of how easy it is to reverse engineer the app in order to find any hard-coded authentication information (such as URLs, passwords, etc)... So, because the server is a web server and not a VPS, that means that all database connections and modifications would need to be done via server-side scripting.

But the client app would still need to make requests to the web server, where some PHP scripts would handle the requests and perform the appropriate actions. So using a url with a php query string still revisits the original hacking issue, and even using HTTP GET/POST requests can easily be packet-sniffed without any decompilation of the game.

So unless I'm missing something, **does the most secure way to do this involve a mixture of direct HTTP GET/POST requests, where the data is somehow encrypted/obfuscated?** Maybe via HTTPS instead of HTTP? Or is there an even better way to do this?

Comment: You won't be able to encrypt/obfuscate your links to a degree that makes them "safe." Typically this is done with some sort of authentication, then that authentication is saved client side and used every request to let the server know who is making that request and what exactly they are requesting.

Comment: Ultimately, a piece of software running under a system that someone else has full control over is not going to be safe. So you have to be clear in your mind over what level of protection you want.   If you want a basic level of encryption built into your app, use Sodium.

Comment: [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page) still has some useful information on web security. Doesn't have to be PHP on the server side either.

Comment: @danblack The web host I'm using currently only supports the basic HTML/PHP/MySQL package. So sadly, for now, it would need to be either PHP or JS.

Comment: @KeithNicholas Eventually, I intend to increase security (and performance) by utilizing a custom-built command-line server running on AWS EC2 and/or similar VPS services, but not for a long while.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expose a RESTful API over HTTPS

Comment: As simple and vague as this answer is, it pointed me to the proper research... Which eventually lead me to switching my host over to [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com), and my scripting platform to *Node.js*, which opened up *a TON* of options, including the easy creation a RESTful API for my Unity project to communicate with... This is especially useful, considering my project is already utilizing the Twitch API, which is also a REST API!

Now, as far as encryption is concerned, HTTPS is certainly the way to go, but will have to wait. For now, I guess can simply obfuscate the server-side data.

Comment: What do you mean by obfuscation of server data? With HTTPS/TLS the whole connection channel is encrypted. Simple as that. 

Heroku supports it out of the box: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/automated-certificate-management

Comment: Did not know that, but now I do, so... Thanks! All I need now is to own a domain name to qualify for the TLS certificate... Which Hostinger provides for free for 1 year (with a measly $0.18 fee from ICANN)... And I thought I'd have to pay an arm and a leg for SSL, lol!